# Declaring an atomic variable inside struct to perform atomic fetch and add instruction on it

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

```
I am trying to evaluate the working of asynchronous push relabel algorithm to find maximum flow in a network using C++ and pthread library. The atomic read-modify-write operation should be implemented by atomic fetch-and-add instructions. I run this code in Eclipse Juno for parallel implementation.
```

I am using 2 structures Edge and Push Relabel. I am not sure how to initialize a variable inside struct as atomic and to perform atomic functions on the variable inside a thread start routine.

Working serial code:(with "cap" variable as non-atomic integer variable)

```
struct Edge  {
  int from, to, cap, flow, index;
  Edge(int from, int to, int cap, int flow, int index) :
     from(from), to(to), cap(cap), flow(flow), index(index) {}

};

struct PushRelabel {
  int N;
  vector<vector<Edge> > G;
  vector<LL> excess;
  vector<int> dist, active, count;
  queue<int> Q;

  PushRelabel(int N) : N(N), G(N), excess(N), dist(N), active(N), count(2*N) {}

  void AddEdge(int from, int to, int cap) {
    G[from].push_back(Edge(from, to, cap, 0, G[to].size()));
    if (from == to) G[from].back().index++;
    G[to].push_back(Edge(to, from, 0, 0, G[from].size() - 1));
  }
```

In the above serial implementation, to make it work in a multithreaded way, I am going to use the atomic fetch-and-add operation on "cap" variable of the structure Edge atomic. So I need to declare the "cap" variable inside Edge structure as atomic. Please tell me how to do it. Please find below the changes I made to the code while attempting to make the "cap" variable atomic.

**Modified code** (Erroneous)(with "cap" variable as atomic integer variable)

```
    #include <atomic>

    struct Edge  {
 // std::atomic<int> cap = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(10);
  int from, to,flow, index;
  std::atomic<int> cap;
  Edge(int from, int to, std::atomic<int> cap , int flow, int index) :
     from(from), to(to), cap(cap), flow(flow), index(index) {}
};

    struct PushRelabel {
  int N;
  vector<vector<Edge> > G;
  vector<LL> excess;
  vector<int> dist, active, count;
  queue<int> Q;
  vector<int> returnexcess;

  PushRelabel(int N) : N(N), G(N), excess(N), dist(N), active(N), count(2*N), returnexcess(N) {}

  void AddEdge(int from, int to, int cap) {
    G[from].push_back(Edge(from, to, cap, 0, G[to].size()));
    if (from == to) G[from].back().index++;
    G[to].push_back(Edge(to, from, 0, 0, G[from].size() - 1));
  }
p is the object created for PushRelabel structure.
```

Below is the operation that needs to be made atomic.

```
p.G[smallestHtVertex][p.G[privQ.front()][smallVindex].index].cap += amt;
```

Am getting the following error in eclipse:
    - use of deleted function ‘std::atomic::atomic(const std::atomic&)’
    - ‘Edge::Edge(Edge&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-
     formed:

I have already included the -std=c++0x flag in the GCC C++ Compiler. Please guide me on this.

Comment: You can replace class members which should be atomic by `atomic<T>`, where `T` represents type of that members. Look at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/) for doc.

Comment: Sorry, am replying after a very long time. It worked amazingly!, thanks a lot